# What is the "level" in World Series of Poker?

Tags: poker

In World Series of Poker each player has a "level" marked with a star in blue as shown below. What does this mean? Is high good or bad? Does WSOP have an explanation of its meaning?

[image]

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, you might try [poker.se] or [gaming.se].

Answer (score 2):

I guess that it is a meter of "experience" in the app.  If so, every action you do in the app increases your level meter (every hand, every win of a hand, etc...)

High level does not mean a strong player, just someone that played on this app for quite some time.  This method known to push players to play and deposit more money.